# Access the parent of an element without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the parent of the li with the value `WAN` without working with IDs? I already tried using `$(this).parent().parent();` in an `onclick` for the `input` but it only returned the clicked `li`.

```
<li>
   <span class="expanded">-</span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Application Integration">Application Integration
   <ul class="">
      <li>
         <span class="expanded">-</span>
         <input type="checkbox" name="Windows">Windows
         <ul class="">
            <li>
               <span class="expanded">-</span>
               <input type="checkbox" name="Leitungen">Leitungen
               <ul class="">
                  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="WAN">WAN</li>
                  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="Mail">Mail</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

How would I access the whole construct (starting at `<input type="checkbox" name="Application Integration">Application Integration`)?

already a huge thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Show your JavaScript. It's not possible to get an `<li>` from `$(this).parent().parent();` based on your html markup. http://jsbin.com/xejefeyuco/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You after something like this?

```js
$('[name="Application Integration"]').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('li').find('[name="WAN"]').closest('li').addClass('xxx');
});
```

```css
.xxx {
    border: solid 3px orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
   <span class="expanded">-</span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Application Integration">Application Integration
   <ul class="">
      <li>
         <span class="expanded">-</span>
         <input type="checkbox" name="Windows">Windows
         <ul class="">
            <li>
               <span class="expanded">-</span>
               <input type="checkbox" name="Leitungen">Leitungen
               <ul class="">
                  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="WAN">WAN</li>
                  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="Mail">Mail</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

or the other way round

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
   $(this).parents('li').last().children('input').not($(this)).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
   <span class="expanded">-</span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Application Integration">Application Integration
   <ul class="">
      <li>
         <span class="expanded">-</span>
         <input type="checkbox" name="Windows">Windows
         <ul class="">
            <li>
               <span class="expanded">-</span>
               <input type="checkbox" name="Leitungen">Leitungen
               <ul class="">
                  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="WAN">WAN</li>
                  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="checkbox" name="Mail">Mail</li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this).parent().closest('li');`

If you are specifically targeting an input you can use:

```
$("input[name='WAN']").click(function(){
    $("input[name]='Application Integration'").addClass("wan-clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need jquery's `.closest` method. It lets you rise through the DOM until you meet a certain selector.

```
$('input[name="WAN"]').click(function(event) {
    var closestli = $(event.target).closest('li');
    var closestul = $(event.target).closest('ul');
    var closestConstruct = $(event.target).closest('input[name="Application Integration"]');
});
```

Like any jquery selection, you can get an empty object if there is no "ancestor" matching your selector.